# I am unable to post questions even though I have positive reputation

Tags: support

I have positive reputation in Server Fault, I also don't have any negative votes on my questions, yet all of a sudden today I see that I am banned from asking questions and I am not allowed to ask any new questions.

Please let me know if this is a genuine ban or some calculation error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authoritative information on post bans is in the post that's linked to in the message you see about the ban.  A summary is:

- The ban is completely automatic, there's nothing a moderator can do about it.
- The ban is based on all your questions, including deleted ones.  You have 5 deleted questions, 3 of them have 0 votes, 2 are -ive.
- A few downvoted questions and several that haven't received any upvotes is enough to trigger the ban.
- It's not a complete ban, it's a severe rate limit: you can ask one question every 6 months.  If a question gets some votes, it might pull you out of the ban.

Comment: I, see, didn't know there were deleted questions. Is there someway I can take a look at the deleted ones? I don't see any on my profile.

Comment: Old deleted questions aren't visible to users.  When I get time, I'll post a list of links to them that you'll be able to click on to see them.  But the most recent is 5 years old, so I don't know if it'll do much good.  A quick glance at a couple questions shows a couple that are probably worth upvoting, so if a couple people do that, you might get out of the ban.

Comment: Thanks @Monica, that would be really nice. I am just curious, what the questions might be. It isn't often that I post queries in Server exchange, so the ban is not that great of an issue. I was just curious why I got it in the first place. I used to think my questions were not that bad, but then as you mentioned maybe I was posting stupid question years back.

Answer (score 1):

> I also don't have any negative votes on my questions

Two of your still-visible questions ("Adding an A record where the hostname has a forward slash" and "Unable to set a cron job in Centos") are voted below-zero, as well as two of your five deleted questions.